# Wrapper of angular component broke css logic

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-components

I would like to make dialog window using SCSS and Angular where you have your own message on the right side and your partner on the left side. But I stuck with component wrappers. I found out that each Angular component has an own wrapper and it's broke my CSS logic. I have a flex container with *flex-direction: column* which contain all my component(
[Box with components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpax6.png)). I set width for this component as *max-content*, but wrapper still take all width of box container. If I set styles for wrapper in Chrome as

```
 align-self: end;
 width: max-content;
```

it become work, but I'm not able to do this from SCSS and I think it's a bad approach working with wrapper of Angular component. Could someone help me with that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try Angular Encapsulation.None